# Is it possible to dynamically work with JSX in React Native?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I've been working with JSX to render layouts in React Native.  Is it possible to dynamically create the JSX instead of hardcoding it?  Or is it better to use something else than JSX?

```
render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.price}>{item.Caption}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.TextBody}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

For example if I wanted to add an additional `<Text>{item.IsFinished}</Text>` element after the other `<Text>` elements (if the data needed it), how could I do that inside the render function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, could do something like `{(condition here) && <Text>{item.IsFinished}</Text>}`

Full code:

```
render() {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.price}>{item.Caption}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.TextBody}</Text>
          {item.IsFinished && <Text>{item.IsFinished}</Text>}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator}/>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Comment: But  is it possible to manipulate the JSX, i.e. directly add a <Text> using Javascript not using JSX Conditions?

Comment: yes you could do something like 
    
    conditionalRender() {
       if (condition === true) {
         return <Text>something</Text>
       } 
       return null
    }

and in your render call this function as 

    render() {
      return (
          <View>
              {this.conditionalRender()}
          </view>
      )
    }